# Getting the URI of a resource located server side in Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I'm very new to silverlight and I'm trying to play a video located in the web project associated with my silverlight application.

What is the best way to get the URI of videos located on the server without hard coding the web address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to the "root" path in silverlight by doing:

`App.Current.Host.Source`

then add the remainder to this address to get the file path of the video you want to play. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You could [pass the URL as parameter](http://www.dotnetspider.com/Silverlight-Tutorial-313.aspx) from the server to the client.

Comment: +1, although that sample is old and still uses the `<asp:Silverlight>` tag, and the code panels on the page don't work properly in FFox.